# Finding $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which satisfies $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R,\ f(f(x+y)-f(x-y))=y^2f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

My question is following.

> Find all $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which satisfies $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R,\ f(f(x+y)-f(x-y))=y^2f(x)$.

At least, the trivial solution $f=0$ can be answer.

At first, I tried $y=0$, then $f(0)=0$.

And I stuck here, so I tried to get injective answer first. then, when $x=0$, then $f(f(y)-f(-y))=0$, so $f(y)=f(-y)$. This contradicts. So there exists no injective answer.

... And? I don't have any idea since then.

Comment: Keep playing round with the functional equation until you have enough information to answer the question. E.g. set $x = y$. Also, check if a polynomial could have this property. This can be done by counting degrees. In the end it's detective work.

Comment: @HansEngler Since it is not guaranteed that this function is a continuous function, I think it is necessary to consider cases defined peicewise. Still, does using polynomial help?

Comment: You can't assume anything about $f$, but you can prove sufficient properties (e.g. f = 0) and necessary properties (e.g. f cannot be a linear function). The more such statements yo collect, the narrower is the range for possible answers, until you find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short outline of a solution.**

If $f$ isn't identical $0$ the expression $y^2f(x)$ takes on all positive or all negative values. Evaluating the functional equation at $(x,x)$ and $(x,-x)$ we get $f(f(2x))=f(-f(2x))$ and therefore $f(x)=f(-x)\ \forall x$.

Swapping $x$ and $y$ we get $y^2f(x)=x^2f(y)$. This leads to the non-trivial solutions $f(x)=\pm\frac{x^2}{4}$.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what did you do after arriving at $y^2f(x)=x^2f(y)$? I was able to form a solution but it looks unnecessarily long to me so I think I'm missing something obvious

Comment: @Amadeus $f$ even $\Rightarrow f(x-y)=f(y-x)$. Then $y^2f(x)=f(f(x+y)-f(x-y))=f(f(y+x)-f(y-x))=x^2f(y)$. $y^2f(x)=x^2f(y) \Rightarrow \frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\frac{f(y)}{y^2}=c(onstant)$. Insert $f(x)=cx^2$ in the functional equation to calculate c.